# State in React not updating as expected

Tags: reactjs, state

In my main `App.js` component I am trying to update my state

```
const[isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated] = useState(false)
```

to true when I load my user given the token I have in local storage.

```
useEffect(() => {
  const loadUser = async () => {
    await fetch('http://localhost:5000/api/auth', {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        'x-auth-token': localStorage.token,
      },
    });

    setIsAuthenticated(true);
  };
  
  loadUser();
}, []);
```

In my return I am rendering a private component...

```
<PrivateRoute exact path='/upload' component={Upload} isAuthenticated={isAuthenticated} />
```

My `PrivateRoute.js` file looks like this...

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, isAuthenticated, ...rest }) => (
  <Route
    {...rest}
    render={(props) =>
      isAuthenticated ? <Component {...props} /> : <Redirect to='/login' />
    }
  />
);
```

Pretty much by passing in the `isAuthenticated` as props to my `PrivateRoute` component I would suppose that the `isAuthenticated` should be updated to `true`. I checked to see if I was loading the user correctly by checking the data I get back from the request I make and indeed I get the user and `setIsAuthenticated` gets called

However When I tried to check what `isAuthenticated` is in my `PrivateRoute` after loading the user I am getting that `isAuthenticated` is `false`

I am not sure why this is the case and would really appreciate some help and explanation.

My App.js file looks like this...

```
const App = () => {
  const [isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const loadUser = async () => {
      await fetch('http://localhost:5000/api/auth', {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
          'x-auth-token': localStorage.token,
        },
      });

      localStorage.setItem('token', localStorage.token);
      setIsAuthenticated(true);
    };

    loadUser();
  }, []);

  return (
    <Router>
      <div className='d-flex flex-row mb-5'>
        <Menu />
        <div className='d-flex flex-column mt-5 w-100'>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
            <Route exact path='/login' component={SignIn} />
            <PrivateRoute
              exact
              path='/upload'
              component={Upload}
              isAuthenticated={isAuthenticated}
            />
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
};
```

Comment: Can you include the *entire* component code for the component rendering the `PrivateRoute`? Have you logged in an effect hook `isAuthenticated` in `PrivateRoute` to see if it is receiving the updated state? What attempted debugging details can you provide?

Comment: In `PrivateRoute` I console logged `isAuthenticated` to see what value it has. I also added how my App.js file looks like

Comment: @MichaelTorres how do you know the console.log is printing after fetching the user? or how do you check the `isAuthenticated` inside `PrivateRoute`?

Comment: "In PrivateRoute I console logged isAuthenticated to see what value it has." And what is *that* value? Do you see it update in `App`'s state? Do you see it update when it changes in state in `App`?

Comment: It should, ae you sure there is no errors in fetch? If theres an error in fetch setIsAuthenticated is not gonna execute

Comment: @DrewReese when I console logged the `isAuthenticated` it says false. I do see though that it updates in my `App` component to `true` which is why I'm confused as to why it isn't being passed with as props to my PrivateRoute component as `true`

Comment: @Kalhan.Toress `fetch` returns a Promise (resolved or rejected), and OP is awaiting it. `fetch` also only rejects on network errors and cancelled requests.

Comment: @Kalhan.Toress yeah, I am sure there is not error. On the server side I actually send back a json response with the user data that I have `email` and `password`. for the purposes of just getting my state `isAuthenticated` to update to `true` I am not using that data now but I did check the response by assigning what I get back to a variable response and after checking I do get back my user data correctly.

Comment: @MichaelTorres put a console.log just before the return and see what you get

Comment: In `PrivateRoute` component I get `false` and in my `App` component I get `true`

Comment: I've copy/pasted your code into a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/state-in-react-not-updating-as-expected-ejmjz) (with mock fetch) and it seems to update in the private route. Can you attempt to distill your code into a running codesandbox that reproduces the issue so that we may try debugging live code?

Comment: Actually, I see what is going on and I guess I overlooked it before when I first checked but in my App.js by console logging `isAuthenticated` it says `false` at first then goes to my `PrivateRoute` component and of course my `isAuthenticated is `false`. Then in my console it prints again from my `App` component `true` but my `PrivateComponent` is never rendered again so that `true` doesn't exists in my `PrivateComponent` I am not sure why this is occurring though

Comment: Okay @DrewReese I will try that I never used it so I'll give it a shot. Thanks for the help!

Comment: here is my [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/beautiful-mountain-6r86i?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Ok, (in the sandbox at least) when manually typing in the address bar to go to the "/upload" route it doesn't work (it is reloading the app, tested by `console.log('MOUNTED!!')` in effect hook on `App`), but if you create a `Link` to that route it works, i.e. `<Link to="/upload">Upload</Link>`.

Comment: Oh actually I think I got confused cause I've been thinking too hard about this problem I will try what you mentioned

Comment: So it works when I do that I just force a redirect when i sign in but why wouldn't it work when I manually type out the url in the address bar?

Answer (score 0):

Try to not use your props in the callback function that are passed.

Use the props straight away like this:

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, isAuthenticated, ...rest }) => {
  return isAuthenticated ? (
    <Route {...rest} render={(props) => <Component {...props} />} />
  ) : (
    <Route {...rest} render={(props) => <Redirect to="/login" />} />
  );
};
```

Or create the callback function with useCallback with the dependencies:

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, isAuthenticated, ...rest }) => {
  const component = useCallback(
    (props) => {
      isAuthenticated ? <Component {...props} /> : <Redirect to="/login" />;
    },
    [isAuthenticated]
  );
  return <Route {...rest} render={component}/>
};
```

Comment: Thanks @RobertTirta I'll take a note of that, but this doesn't solve my issue

Answer (score -1):

for problem like this, redux is best solution

in your app.js dispatch action to set isAuthenticate flag

```
store.dispatch(setIsAuthenticated(true))
```

in other files where isAuthenticate is required simply use

```
mapStateToProps
```

Comment: Thanks but i've done it using redux. I am trying to do it without redux